# Generalised Linked List

Tags: linked-list

I was studying Generalised Linked Lists. I understood the simple method of creating them properly, but now I want to use them to store any n-variable polynomial. I tried it on my own but could not do it. I searched on google, but to no avail. 
I want to know whether there is any good tutorial for polynomial using GLLs. Is there any such tutorial?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing on line#42.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a structure with the coefficient of x and its exponent and create a linked list of it.

```
typedef struct poly
{
  int coff, expo;
  struct poly nxt;
} term;
```

You can use the above structure for your linked list to create a n-variable polynomial.
Now you can add as many terms to your linked list as you like until you reach the nth term where you want to stop.